# How to resolve Trying to access array offset on value of type null error?

Tags: php, function

WHAT:

So I cannot for the life of me figure out why I'm getting this error. I'm trying to create a function that will display the user information from the database in a table but I have like a ton of these errors on the page and I don't know whats wrong.

STEPS TO RESOLVE:

So I've gone over my code a bunch of types to make sure that all the variables and what not were spelled correctly and as far as I can tell they are.

I've also googled this issue to see if I can find a solution but none of them are very helpful.

I honestly don't know whats wrong so kinda hard to find ways to resolve an issue, I don't even really know what this error means.

THE CODE:

This is the function:

```
<?php
        function display_table($fields, $data, $rows, $page){
      if(isset($_GET['page'])){
        $page = $_GET['page'];
      } else {
        $page = 1;
      }
      $firstRecord = ($page - 1) * ROWS_PER_PAGE;
      $pageNumbers = ceil($rows / ROWS_PER_PAGE);
    
      echo '<div class="table-responsive w-75 mx-auto py-3">
      <table class="table table-dark table-bordered table-sm">
      <thead>
      <tr>';
    
      foreach($fields as $key){
        echo '<th class="py-2">' . $key . '</th>';
      }
    
      echo '</tr>
      </thead>
      </tbody>';
    
      $keys = array_keys($fields);
    
      for($record = $firstRecord; $record < $firstRecord + ROWS_PER_PAGE; $record++){
        $row = $data[$record];
        echo '<tr>';
    
        for($recordCount = 0; $recordCount < count($keys); $recordCount++){
          $column = $keys[$recordCount];
          echo '<td class="py-2">' . $row[$column] . '</td>';
        }
    
        echo '</tr>';
      }
    
      echo '</tbody>
      </table';
    
      for($pages = 1; $pages <= $pageNumbers; $pages++){
        echo '<a class="btn btn-dark mx-1" href=?page=' . $pages . '</a>';
      }
    }
    
    ?>
```

This is where the function is put into action:

```
<?php
   display_table(
     array(
      "id" => "Id",
      "emailaddress" => "Email",
      "firstname" => "First Name",
      "lastname" => "Last Name",
      "salesperson" => "Salesperson",
      "phonenumber" => "Phone Number",
      "extension" => "Extension",
      "type" => "Type"
    ),
    client_select_all(),
    client_count(),
    1
  );
   ?>
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

NOTE: client_select_all and client_count are other functions, don't know if you'll need to see those or not

Comment: Which line does the error occur on?

Comment: The error means you're doing `$some_variable[1]` when `$some_variable` is null. The error message also tells you exactly what line the problem is on, which should help you solve your problem.

Comment: it says it is on line 132 which is this one:  echo '<td class="py-2">' . $row[$column] . '</td>';